# Designing reward function in RL best practices

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I created a real simple custom Pygame Mario nock off where I was hoping to train an agent with stable baselines 3 algorithms in a custom open AI gym environment.

It looks like this where Mario has to make 3 hops and the question box is the finish line or best reward. This is the [Pygame script](https://github.com/bbartling/Building-Automation-Game-Bridge/blob/develop/RL/pygameStuff/game.py) I made and then converted into [an open AI Gym environment](https://github.com/bbartling/Building-Automation-Game-Bridge/blob/develop/RL/pygameStuff/rl_game.py). The basics of it is Mario has to jump the way up to the top without falling off a platform and if he hits the question box that is the finish or biggest reward.

[image: Pygame window]
There is only 3 moves Mario can make jump, move right, or move left. Would anyone have any advice to try? It seems like the stable baseline PPO algorithm works where the agent does explore the environment when I watch it attempt the game but it seems like no matter what I try when the learning stops the agent just learns to either jump off the edge immediately where Mario spawns or just jump up and down without any attempt at getting to the top. Its like my reward function is the biggest hurdle: (I think) This is the basics of the open AI gym step function below, would anyone have any tips to try for better reward?

```
max_moves= 150
reward = 0
step() # on start method

# Reward for moving left
reward += -10  

# Reward for moving right
reward += -10 

# Check if Mario has not exceeded maximum jumps
reward += 25

# Huge penalty for exceeding jump limit
reward -= 1500  

# Penalty for standing still
reward -= 1000

# Handle collisions with platforms
for platform in platforms:
# Check if Mario has jumped up to the next platform
               reward += 2500  # Reward for jumping up to the next platform
reward -= 150  # Penalty for not jumping enough

reward -= 5000  # Penalty for falling off
reward += 5000  # Reward for reaching the question box

done
```

Comment: You need a matrix representing all of the possible actions (move left, move right, jump, etc.) that mario can do at every location in the world (grid). You probably don't want to include actions that lead to moving out of bounds. Reward should be negative for moves that result in mario being farther away from the target goal location, positive reward for moves that make him closer to the target goal location. You probably want a gradient if there are moderately bad or moderately good moves. Start with a smaller world (grid) so only 5 or so moves are needed to reach the target goal location.

Comment: reward can be scaled by the distance mario is from the target goal location minus the previous location mario was at. You don't need to have a weights for the locations in the world (grid) itself, unless you want this to be an actor-critic model; but it could work with just weights for the actions themselves.

Comment: Besides the number of training iterations determining the training trials, you could also have "best path" or "fewest moves to target" as another criteria where the training loop (while loop here instead of a for loop) runs until mario uses the fewest number of moves needed to reach the target goal location.

Comment: Okay thanks guys for the feed back ill try to make the game even smaller. I can solve it myself in 5 jumps

Comment: @OriYarden how would you go about creating a matrix of all possible moves (left, right, jump) in a small game like this? Even in this small example this would be quite large (I think), is that a concept more for creating a Q learning table?

Comment: right, the matrix would be the square of the (world) grid size times the number of actions or moves that are possible: `import numpy as np`, `grid_size = 5`, `current_pos = [0, 0]`, `world_grid = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size)).astype(float)`, `world_grid[current_pos[0], current_pos[1]] = 1.0`, `number_of_actions = 3 # 0 = Left; 1 = Right; 2 = jump`, `weights = np.reshape(np.random.random(number_of_actions*grid_size**2)*0.01, [grid_size**2, number_of_actions])`. Since it's a weights matrix, it should start off with random values. Not sure if you'd want to combine actions (e.g. jump right).

Comment: I just made a github and uploaded a grid search algo example (https://github.com/OriYarden/Path-Finding-and-Object-Tracking-using-Machine-Learning-AI-from-Scratch-numpy-only-in-Python) if you want to check it out.

Comment: Thanks Wow. @OriYarden if you created an answer ill hit the green box.